# Incoming Call reseting EditText value in Activity/Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this is very strange behaviour of Android that I've found so far.
I create an android application to input data from EditText,,,but once a call is coming. The value that I've wrote in EditText was cleared. I tried create a session every 5s and load it back on resume but still no works.

Maybe someone understand this behaviour and can explain further.
Thanks

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 1):

Inside onCreate add this,

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, This might be happening because of the Telephony framework as it has the highest priority in android when you receive a call, By default, the TelephonyManager Invoked and PhoneActivity (IDK the real name of the UI) cames on top so that you can pick the call up or hang it up.
            but because of that, your activity goes in onStop() and its state has cleared so does the text in your EditText.A similar thing happens when we rotate the device.

what you can do prevent this is to by Saving and Restoring the state of activity

Example:  override these methods inside the activity.

```
   @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      savedInstanceState.putString("old_text", yourEditText.getText());  
   }
```

and then

```
  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
       String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("old_text");
       yourEditText.setText(myString);
    }
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: this one is also not working...wait I'll share my code